# How to delete statefulsets.apps using Kubernetes Python CoreV1API

Tags: python, kubernetes, statefulset

I'm migrating `helm2` releases to `helm3`. One of my resources is `redis` and it's protected from migration. I have to remove it using

```sh
kubectl delete statefulsets.apps --cascade=false -nkube-system testme-redis-master
```

I wanna use the `Kubernetes` python lib, only that I cannot find the matching function.
I'm using `CoreV1API`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wanna use the Kubernetes python lib, only that I cannot find the matching function.

You must look in the right API Group.

> I'm using CoreV1API.

`StatefulSets` is in `AppsV1` and not in `CoreV1`, so check that API Group instead.

See the Python Kubernetes client [example for Deployment in AppsV1 API Group](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/deployment_create.py), it is very similar to `StatefulSet`

Comment: this was the right-pointing tip for me. with [@krishna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5147259/krishna-chaurasia) response, I was able to get the desired documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the [following reference doc link](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md) which has reference for all the AppsV1 APIs including API usage for [deleting the statefulset](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#delete_namespaced_stateful_set).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AppsV1Api`, where you have `delete_namespaced_stateful_set` method.

https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#delete_namespaced_stateful_set